# How can I use select in null for an SSRS Report Parameter?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS Report that passes a value to my stored procedure. In the stored procedure, I have the following:

```
select * from ItemTable where Items in @ItemValues
```

Previously, this will work as @ItemValues can be multiple values between 1 to 5. However, now a null check has to be done so how can I do this with a null statement ?

Comment: try  @Input1 IS NULL

Comment: It will not work unless you have some dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement in your procedure .

```
select * from ItemTable where  @ItemValues IS NULL OR Items in @ItemValues
```